# Задача по функциям и двухмерным массивам на c++

Tags: c++, массивы, функции

Поняла как делать манипуляцию с первыми строкой и столбцом, но автоматизировать процесс не получается.

Задача:
Преобразовать каждый из массивов по правилу: деление элементов 1-го
столбца на сумму положительных элементов 1-ой строки, элементы, 2-го
столбца на сумму положительных элементов 2-ой строки и т.д.
Массивы с равным количеством строк и столбцов.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Ну массивы, похоже, двумерные, а код `Поняла как делать манипуляцию` стоит показать, там достаточно индекс менять